# Is there a control character to start a printer?

Tags: controls, printing

How  to control the printer to start printing using printer's control language?
I know there exist some commands to control the printer but I haven't found it yet.
So I wondering how the printer knows when it could start printing?

Comment: The printer's control language varies/depends on the type of printer.

Answer (score 1):

It's really very complicated, and largely depends on what sort of printer you're talking about.  One example would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P

Many modern printer speak Postscript, PCL 5 or even PDF, and do the whole network printing protocols themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Most printers support PJL (printer job language).  The most common final command in the PJL header sequence is ENTER LANGUAGE = "xxx".  Here you would put PCL etc.

If PJL isn't supported then most printers will 'sniff' the stream to try and determine what the language is and when to start processing the data.

See here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Job_Language

If you want more specifics or examples just add a comment to my answer and I can provide more detail.

If I've read your question incorrectly and you are looking for something like 'page eject' which would cause the printer to actually start printing the page, then you would look to each print language.  In PCL that would be a formfeed character.  In Postcript a showpage etc.